# How to display child HTML element over top of area cleared by parent element clip-path?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

See https://jsfiddle.net/scott8035/gqn0t9a7/3/.

In this example, I have a section of a page content box displayed with a box shadow only on left & right sides. I achieve that effect by adding `clip-path: inset(0 -10px);` to the content box's CSS. So far, everything is good.

There is an element inside the content box. When you hover over it, a drop-down menu appears. However, the menu is also clipped by the clip-path from the parent content box instead of being displayed in its entirety.

How can I display the menu child element over the top of the clipped area so you can see the entire thing?

Note: I am somewhat hampered in how I can structure the HTML because I'm using a page builder, notably, the menu has to be a child element of the content box.

Here is the code in case the jsfiddle doesn't work:

```
<body>
    <div id="content-box">
        <div class="hoverable">
            <p>
                Element 1
            </p>        
            <p>
                Element 2
            </p>        
            <p>
                Element 3
            </p>   
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu item 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}

#content-box {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    clip-path: inset(0 -10px);
}

.hoverable {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
}

.hoverable:hover .menu {
    display: block;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 172px;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #333;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the trick to a pseudo element instead:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

#content-box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  position:relative;
}
#content-box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
  clip-path: inset(0 -10px);
  pointer-events:none;
}
.hoverable {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hoverable:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 172px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content-box">
    <div class="hoverable">
      <p>
        Element 1
      </p>
      <p>
        Element 2
      </p>
      <p>
        Element 3
      </p>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you much for the answer...but why does it work?

Comment: because the clip-path no more apply to the main element, it apply to a pseudo element which is considered as a child of the main element so it's no more a wrapper to your content. In other words, I moved the effect from the container to another element to avoid affecting the childs